# Deploying QuantLib in Dockerfile fails

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, quantlib

I am trying to build a simple Docker image with a python script that uses numpy, pandas and QuantLib, but Quantlib fails to install with pip, and while I have been able to install it with apt-get, my python script cannot recognise it. Not sure what is going wrong; any help appreciated!

My requirements.txt:

```
conda install pip -y
pip install numpy==1.22.3
pip install pandas==1.4.2
pip install QuantLib==1.29
conda install boto3
```

My Dockerfile:

```
COPY requirements.txt /home/app/
RUN chmod 755 /home/app/requirements.txt
RUN /home/app/requirements.txt
```

The error message:

```
#0 25.49 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QuantLib==1.26 (from versions: none)
#0 25.49 ERROR: No matching distribution found for QuantLib==1.26
```